# UI-Router ui-sref-active throws error when using ui-sref params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu, where clicking the parent link produces the dropdown list (default behaviour).  The dropdown list of the parent is built using ngRepeat from an array of navigation data, and each has a ui-router state parameter, so it looks like:

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Parent Link
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

        <li ng-repeat="item in navCtrl.items()" 
            ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="some.state({ paramKey: paramValue })">
                {{item.link}}
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

But, even though it does seem to drop the active class on my link it throws this error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about the answer, but, as far as I know, why would you use `navCtrl.items()` using brackets? I have never seen it used like that before. Wouldn't the old `item in items` ng-repeat work? Sorry if it does not help at all.

Comment: I had no idea that I shouldn't invoke a function call in ngRepeat.  I'm still very new to AngularJS, so I just did something that I could have done in a for loop.

Comment: For others searching for a solution: An ng-if directive on the same element as the ui-sref-active directive can also invoke this error.